# How can I modify data using a variable field name?

Tags: python, dbf

I am trying to create a program that modify different dbf file but since each file have different field name, I am unsure if the python dbf library have the option to specify the field with string.

To modify the data without variable

```
dbf.write(record, CUSTOM2="Hello")
```

But when I tried this, it gives an error

```
dbf.write(record, {'CUSTOM2': "Hello"})
```

TypeError: write() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Try `dbf.write(record, **{'CUSTOM2': "Hello"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to update records in dbf files:

- use the record as a context manager:

```py
    target_field = 'custom2'
    with record:
        record[target_field] = "Hello"
```

- or use the `write` function with keywords:

```py
    target_field = 'custom2'
    update = {target_field: "Hello"}
    dbf.write(record, **update)
```